# Cubic 3-fold singular along a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, birational-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Does there exists a cubic or quartic $3$-fold $X\subset\mathbb{P}^4$ such that $Sing(X)$ is a smooth curve $C$ of genus $g(C)\geq 2$ and $X$ has $A_1$-singularities along $C$?

Comment: No. If $\operatorname{Sing}(X) =C$ every bisecant line to $C$ must be contained in $X$. This implies easily that $C$ is rational.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. Do you know if there exists a quartic 3-fold with this property?

Comment: I think so. Let $C$ be a general complete intersection of 3 quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$, given by $P=Q=R=0$. The quartic threefold $X$ defined by $P^2+Q^2+R^2=0$ has $\operatorname{Sing}(X)=C $. Now I don't know what you call "$A_1$-singularities along $C$", but the singularities of $X$ along $C$ are as nice as they can be.